# Sql query runs in PgAdmin but fails in PowerBI

Tags: sql, powerbi

I am trying to run a SQL query in PowerBI but it always fails with "EnableFolding Error". I have tried different solutions like making EnableFolding=false but with no luck! I believe my query can be optimized but since I am a beginner in writing SQL queries, I need some help from experts.
Here is my SQL query -

```
select sub1.*, sub2.mem2, sub2.cp_attr1 from 
(SELECT sub.customer as mem1, sub.data_attr1, sub.data_attr2 as lic_attr2, sub.timestamp  FROM(
    SELECT  customer,  data_attr1, data_attr2, timestamp,
            max(timestamp) OVER
            (
                PARTITION by customer
                
            ) AS max_timestamp 
    FROM tableA where name = 'P' 
    ) sub 
WHERE sub.timestamp >= max_timestamp - interval '1 hour' ) sub1
join
(SELECT sub.customer as mem2, sub.data_attr1 as cp_attr1, sub.timestamp FROM(
    SELECT  customer,  data_attr1, timestamp,
            max(timestamp) OVER
            (
                PARTITION by customer
                
            ) AS max_timestamp
    FROM tableA where name = 'Q' 
    ) sub 
WHERE sub.timestamp >= max_timestamp - interval '1 hour') sub2
on sub1.mem1 = sub2.mem2 
where REPLACE(sub1.lic_attr2, ' ', '')  like CONCAT(CONCAT('%', REPLACE(REPLACE(sub2.cp_attr1, ' ', ''), '/', '')), '%')
```

I am trying to get latest records per customer and also records which are 1 hour older to the latest timestamp. This query runs in PgAdmin but doesn't run in PowerBI. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try removing [EnableFolding=true] from query, advance editor (the one showing the m language)

Comment: I have done that as well but with no luck